# What is the chance of failure of exception code block

Tags: python, exception

#### Question:

Is there any chances that the `finally` block of a python code may not be executed while operating system is still running?

#### Purpose:

I need to control a machine with a Linux box. The squarewave signal for the step motor is produced by an external program in the same environment and if I couldn't stop the squarewave signal for a reason, machine would physically get damaged. So, it's very important to call the external program's stop method in any case, no matter how my application is crashed.

Comment: Show something...or please explain what do you want to ask..

Comment: A chance? Sure. Power outage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions):

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement,
>   whether an exception has occurred or not. When an exception has
>   occurred in the try clause and has not been handled by an except
>   clause (or it has occurred in a except or else clause), it is
>   re-raised after the finally clause has been executed. The finally
>   clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other clause of the
>   try statement is left via a break, continue or return statement.

Anyway, under certain circumstances (e.g., the program crashes), it can still happen that the program does not enter the finally statement, but at this point to prevent resources open (e.g., database sessions) after a program crash, you need to use a different mechanism (monitoring, and so on).

Comment: Monitoring is the last resort. It will get the code more complicated. Maybe there is an option to run `finally` block as a separate process? Would it help?

Comment: You could make another script which checks if the first program is running, if it's not it will call the stop method. To be really sure it will run I would run this second script in another server/machine and link them with a DB of some sort.

Comment: Okay, I'm convinced that monitoring is the way to go. Thank you all.

Comment: Well, "another script which checks ..." is exactly what monitoring does :) PS: it depends on what your program does. Is it a web service? Does it provide a network interface? Because there are already several monitoring tools, like Zabbix, JMX for Java and so on.